# How to make custom shader receive shadow in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

The original post is here https://discourse.threejs.org/t/please-help-me-find-the-error-in-my-shader/2924/7
Seems it is a non trivial work, because the lack of documentation and example in three.js website about this topic.

So far, I can make it render the right picture, and with the kindly help from @Mugen87 , it can cast shadow too, but it still can not receive shadow.

This is the lastest code from above link, I write here so people can see it directly，

```js
var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
        THREE.UniformsLib.fog,
        THREE.UniformsLib.lights,
        THREE.UniformsLib.shadowmap,
        {
            mapMain: {value: null},
            mapGlow: {value: null}
        }
    ]),
    vertexShader: [
        "uniform vec4 offsetRepeat;",

        "varying vec3 vNormal;",
        "varying vec2 vUv;",

        "varying vec3 vViewPosition;",


        "varying vec3 fPosition;",
        "varying vec2 vUvM;",


        THREE.ShaderChunk.common,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_pars_begin,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.shadowmap_pars_vertex,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.fog_pars_vertex,

            // "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",
        "void main(){",
                // THREE.ShaderChunk.beginnormal_vertex,
                // THREE.ShaderChunk.defaultnormal_vertex,
                "vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",
                "vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",

                "vViewPosition = - mvPosition.xyz;",

                "vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix *normal );",

                // "vUv = uv * offsetRepeat.zw + offsetRepeat.xy;",
                // "vUvM = uv * offsetRepeat.zw + offsetRepeat.xy;",

                "vUv = uv ;",
                "vUvM = uv;",

                "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;",

                // THREE.ShaderChunk.begin_vertex,
                // THREE.ShaderChunk.project_vertex,
                // THREE.ShaderChunk.worldpos_vertex,
                // //THREE.ShaderChunk.logdepthbuf_vertex,
                // "fPosition = position;",
                THREE.ShaderChunk.shadowmap_vertex,
                THREE.ShaderChunk.fog_vertex,
            "}"
    ].join("\n"),
    fragmentShader: [

        "uniform sampler2D mapMain;",
        "uniform sampler2D mapGlow;",

        THREE.ShaderChunk.common,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.bsdfs,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.packing,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.shadowmap_pars_fragment,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.fog_pars_fragment,

        // THREE.ShaderChunk.dithering_pars_fragment,
        // THREE.ShaderChunk.emissivemap_pars_fragment,
        // // THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_pars,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_pars_begin,
        THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_pars_maps,
        // THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_phong_pars_fragment,
        // THREE.ShaderChunk.specularmap_pars_fragment,

        "varying vec3 vNormal;",
        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "varying vec2 vUvM;",

        "varying vec3 vViewPosition;",
        

        "void main(){",

            // "vec3 outgoingLight = vec3( 0.0 );", // outgoing light does not have an alpha, the surface does
            // "vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );",

            "vec4 mainColor = texture2D(mapMain, vUv);",
            "vec3 glowColor = texture2D(mapGlow, vUvM).rgb;",
            "vec3 glow = (1.0 - mainColor.a) * glowColor;",

            // THREE.ShaderChunk.specularmap_fragment,
            "vec3 normal = normalize( vNormal );",

            // "vec3 viewerDirection = normalize( vViewPosition );",
            "vec3 viewPosition = normalize( vViewPosition );",

            "vec3 totalDiffuseLight = vec3( 0.0 );",
            "vec3 totalSpecularLight = vec3( 0.0 );",

            // directional lights

            "#if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0",

                "vec3 dirDiffuse = vec3( 0.0 );",
                "vec3 dirSpecular = vec3( 0.0 );",

                "for( int i = 0; i < NUM_DIR_LIGHTS; i++ ) {",

                    "vec3 dirVector = directionalLights[ i ].direction;",
                    "vec3 dirHalfVector = normalize( dirVector + viewPosition );",

                    "float dirDotNormalHalf = max( dot( normal, dirHalfVector ), 0.0 );",
                    "float dirDiffuseWeight = max( dot( normal, dirVector ), 0.0 );",

                    // "float dirSpecularWeight = specularTex.r * max( pow( dirDotNormalHalf, shininess ), 0.0 );",

                    "totalDiffuseLight += directionalLights[ i ].color * dirDiffuseWeight;",
                    // "totalSpecularLight += directionalLights[ i ].color * specular * dirSpecularWeight * dirDiffuseWeight;",

                "}",

            "#endif",

            // THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_phong_fragment,
            //THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_template,
            THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_fragment_begin,
            THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_fragment_maps,
            THREE.ShaderChunk.lights_fragment_end, 
            "gl_FragColor = vec4((mainColor.rgb + glow) * totalDiffuseLight, 1.0);",
            // THREE.ShaderChunk.shadowmap_fragment,

            // THREE.ShaderChunk.tonemapping_fragment,
            // THREE.ShaderChunk.encodings_fragment,
            // THREE.ShaderChunk.premultiplied_alpha_fragment,
            // THREE.ShaderChunk.dithering_fragment,
            THREE.ShaderChunk.fog_fragment,
        "}"
    ].join("\n")
});
```

And the error:

```
three.js:15911 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined
    at StructuredUniform.setValue (three.js:15911)
    at StructuredUniform.setValue (three.js:15911)
    at Function.WebGLUniforms.upload (three.js:16039)
    at setProgram (three.js:23023)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (three.js:21797)
    at renderObject (three.js:22556)
    at renderObjects (three.js:22526)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:22288)
    at GameModel.update (main.js:1632)
    at render (main.js:2555)
```

Answer (score 1):

need to add lighting flags

```
var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms:...,
    vertexShader:...,
    fragmentShader:...,

    lights: true // add this,
    fog: true,
    transparent: true
});
```